# Can the Python apt API detect, a package is "held"?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I used the method specified [here](/questions/18654/) to put a "hold" on a particular package ("jenkins") to keep the system from upgrading it:

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep jenkins
jenkins                                         hold
```

Is there any way I get detect this special status using the Python API for apt? Much as I drill into the `Package`, `Record`, and `Version` objects, I do not see any mention of the package being "held".

I really loath spawning off a `dpkg`-process to do this... Any hope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it -- by looking inside `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade`. The `apt.Package`-object, actually, has a member named `_pkg`, which is of type `apt_pkg.Package`. That one has a `selected_state` member -- a numeric constant (an enum). This is, what I use in my code now:

```
    import apt
    import apt_pkg
    ...
    if package._pkg.selected_state == apt_pkg.SELSTATE_HOLD:
        pkg['hold'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this functionality does not seem to be exposed in the Python API. They have `marked_delete`, `marked_downgrade`, `marked_install`, etc., but not `marked_held`. However, it does exist in the [C++ API](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.selected_state). Any chance you can use that?